# Getting access to r_basicprofile when I already have permission on LinkedIn api v2

Tags: linkedin-api

After numerous exchanges with LinkedIn "Experts" none of them was able to help and do anything but copy paste the FAQ.

I'm preparing a client's platform for the v2 migration and encountered major problems for getting user data.

I currently have access to many fields including the `r_basicprofile` as can be seen in my app's auth tab:

[image: auth tab]

However upon requesting the endpoint

`/me` I get the following error:

> Not enough permissions to access: GET /me

I have also searched the new API documentation and there is no mention on how to request access to the `r_basicprofile` same on the FAQ the only link I could find was this one:

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

However it doesn't specify which one gives access to `r_basicprofile`

Our app is aimed at professionals and we require access to more info than just first, last name and email. Currently we work with positions, headlines and more.

How can I get access to the r_basicprofile and specifically the following fields:

'headline','summary','positions','specialties','location','industry','current-share','num-connections','num-connections-capped',

Comment: got the exact same issue... no answer yet though... sorry dude ☹️